# Complex forms with many variables

Tags: usability, forms, layout, interface, simplicity

I'm really striggling to simplify this data set. I need all the information as chosen inputs so the system is able to read the input and spit out a rate at any request. I'm really not sure on how further to simplify. This looks horrid too. :/

This is the data set i have to work from:

[image: complex data set]

And this is the current solve in terms of interface.. but it aint pretty.

[image: Current Complex set up for the inputs]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to display all the inputs to the user in the same screen, or could you divide the process in steps?

Comment: I think this is an ideal case for a form wizard / multi-step process; as sets of inputs take context from previous selections.

Comment: What is the process you are trying to design for? Is this a advanced filter or a entering of ticket information? What exactly you have to do with this data?

Comment: @Alvaro, It's difficult to put on different screens, but I could definitely ask a question up front to segment the options.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, yes, the form wouldn't be as complex with the drop downs and input fields once initial info is inputted, but not a lot of the inputs can be simplified.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov it's for entering rate ticketing information. The inputs would reference other rates in order to find the rate for the specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This has the potentially for becoming very confusing and slow. Your example reminded me of the app [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) which has a very similar UX. You can add scenarios and conditions just like in your example.

They show a separate window to edit a scenario from the list of scenarios. You could probably do the same.

My suggestion below allows you to quickly read all rules without the clutter of input fields. I simplified it a bit, but you can do it whoever you want. If you just have dozens of active inputs all the time, it's very confusing and potentially slow and heavy.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVBmuS.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>